# Mandar información de un item a otra clase en un RecyclerView con Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, kotlin, recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

estoy inflando un RecyclerView con información de Firebase y a la hora de mandar informacion del item pulsado a otra activity me surge un problema. Necesito madnar el texto que aparece en el nombre del item, y no se como hacerlo. Estoy usando 3 clases para todo este proceso:

Habito.java:

public class Habito {

```
private String nombre;
private String descripcion;
private String tipo;
private String fecha;
private Spinner tipo2;

public Habito() {

}

public Habito(String nombre, String descripcion, String tipo, String fecha) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public String getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(String fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}
}
```

HabitoAdapter.java:

```
open class HabitoAdapter(options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Habito?>) :
FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Habito, HabitoAdapter.ViewHolder>(options), View.OnClickListener {

private var listener: View.OnClickListener? = null


override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.activity_view_habitos, viewGroup, false)
    view.setOnClickListener(this)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, habito: Habito) {
    holder.tv_nombre.text = habito.nombre
    holder.tv_descripcion.text = habito.descripcion
    holder.tv_tipo.text = habito.tipo
    holder.tv_fecha.text = habito.fecha

}

fun setOnClickListener(listener: View.OnClickListener?) {
    this.listener = listener
}

override fun onClick(view: View) {
    if (listener != null) {
        listener!!.onClick(view)
    }
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var tv_nombre: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombre)
    var tv_descripcion: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Descripcion)
    var tv_tipo: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tipo)
    var tv_fecha: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_fechaInicio)
}


}
```

En la siguiente clase tengo comentado el método onClick, que dentro tiene un intent con un putExtra que debería mandar el TextView que hay en el item pero no lo hace, ya que no se como acceder exactamente en el momento que se infla
MostrarDatos.kt:

```
public class MostrarDatos extends AppCompatActivity /*implements HabitoAdapter.OnItemClickListener*/ {
RecyclerView recyclerViewHabitos;
HabitoAdapter mAdapter;
FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
RecyclerView.RecyclerListener listener;
/*
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MostrarDatos.this, MostrarHabito.class);

    String Str_nombre = recibirExtra2();
    i.putExtra("nombre2", getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre2"));

    startActivity(i);
}

 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar_datos);

    //Asociar el recyclerView
    recyclerViewHabitos = findViewById(R.id.recyclerHabitos);
    recyclerViewHabitos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    //Inicializar Firebase Auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    //Asignar el correo del usuario activo a una variable de tipo String
    String txt_correo = currentUser.getEmail();

    //Crear la consulta
    Query query = mFirestore.collection(txt_correo).whereEqualTo("horario", recibirExtra());

    //Ejecutar la consulta
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Habito> firestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Habito>()
            .setQuery(query, Habito.class).build();

    mAdapter = new HabitoAdapter(firestoreRecyclerOptions/*, this*/);

    //setOnClickListener();

    /*Al seleccionar un item nos manda a una clase en la que se muestra toda la información mas detallada
    mAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MostrarDatos.this, MostrarHabito.class);

            TextView nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_nombre);

            String Str_nombre = nombre.getText().toString();
            i.putExtra("nombre", Str_nombre);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

     */

    //Mantener el recyclerView actualizado siempre que se esté en la app
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    recyclerViewHabitos.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //Método para volver a HomeScreen
    volver();

}

/*
private void setOnClickListener() {
    listener = new RecyclerView.RecyclerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), );
        }
    };
}

 */

//Regresar al inicio de la app
public void volver() {
    Button btn_back = findViewById(R.id.button_Back2);
    btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent iHome = new Intent(MostrarDatos.this, HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(iHome);
        }
    });
}

//Método para recibir el horario, ya sea mañana, tarde o noche
public String recibirExtra() {
    return getIntent().getStringExtra("horario");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mAdapter.stopListening();
}
}
```

Comment: Lo puedes hacer desde el `Adapter`, y si implementas el Componente de Navegación todo será mucho más sencillo (viendo el `Intent` supongo que quieres pasar los datos a otra parte).

Comment: Si lo hago desde el Adapter, ¿tendría que ser dentro del método OnClick? Con el Intent lo que quiero es acceder a una activity en la que muestro todo de manera mas detallada y a su vez hay implementado un botón que me permite eliminar la información en firestore.

Comment: Claro, desde el `onClick`. La cuestión es que desde el Adapter tienes a mano la instancia completa del objeto `Habito` sobre el que se hizo click, pudiendo acceder a cualquiera de sus propiedades.